# How to format a CF card by a terminal command?

Tags: command-line, partition, mkfs

I want to know the command for formatting a compact flash card from the terminal.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. We'ĺl need more information than that. what filesystem do you want to format it as? Is the card recognized by your machine? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If the CF is installed in the system and you want to format it with EXT4 you simply do this.

#### Step #1 - identify the device

Using either the output of `dmesg` or `blkid` or `fdisk -l`, determine the devices identification on the system.

*dmesg*

```
$ dmesg
SCSI device sdd: 31275008 512-byte hdwr sectors (16013 MB)
sdd: Write Protect is off
sdd: Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
sdd: assuming drive cache: write through
SCSI device sdd: 31275008 512-byte hdwr sectors (16013 MB)
sdd: Write Protect is off
sdd: Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
sdd: assuming drive cache: write through
 sdd: sdd1
```

*blkid*

```
$ sudo blkid
...
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="NIKON D7000" UUID="0000-0000" TYPE="vfat"
```

*fdisk*

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
...
Disk /dev/sdd: 16.0 GB, 16012804096 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1946 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1        1947    15633408    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Once you've determined that the device is `/dev/sdd` or whatever your device happens to be you simply use `mkfs.ext4` to format it.

#### Step #2 - (optional) partition the device

**NOTE:** You might want to partition it but you aren't obligated to do so. You can use `fdisk` to partition the device.

#### Step #3 - format the device

Here I'm formatting it with EXT3 but the process is essentially the same.

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdd1
mke2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
1954560 inodes, 3908352 blocks
195417 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=4005560320
120 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
16288 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208

Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

This filesystem will be automatically checked every 24 mounts or
180 days, whichever comes first.  Use tune2fs -c or -i to override.
$
```

#### Step #4 - test the device

Now attempt to mount it and touch a file to confirm that the formatting worked correctly.

*mount it*

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/
```

*check it*

```
$ sudo blkid
...
/dev/sdd1: UUID="33f02391-b15a-4f0a-859c-5b098b2a38fb" TYPE="ext3" 

$ df -h /mnt/
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1              15G  166M   14G   2% /mnt
```

*test write it*

```
$ sudo touch /mnt/afile
$ ls -l /mnt/afile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 15 13:27 /mnt/afile
```

*unmount it*

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
```